# Is there a Ctrl+B equivalent of PyCharm in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm, ide

In PyCharm, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> can help me to navigate through the chain of keywords in a `.robot` file.
Is there a similar keyboard shortcut in VS Code?

Comment: have you looked at all the Robot extensions

Answer (score 1):

The "CTRL/COMMAND+B" equivalent of PyCharm in VSCode is "F12" with the cursor on the function(or variable...) you're searching for, or simply "CTRL+Click".
You could also go to the "GO" window on the top left and click on "Go to definition".